# Saving R dataframe from script

Tags: r, dataframe, save

It should be very simple, but for now cannot figure it out. Say I create a generic dataframe with some data in a loop, let's call it `df`.

Now I want to assign a specific name to it and want to save it to specific destination.  I generate two character variables - filename and file_destination and try to use the following in the script code:

```
assign(filename, df)

save(filename, file = file_destination)
```

Of course it save just a string with a name in the file and not the actual data.

How do i save the dataframe created via `assign(filename,df)`?

Comment: Try `save(list=filename,file=file_destination)`. Also, use better names for your variables. `filename` for an object which is not a file name is very odd.

Comment: Great, it worked, thank you! I knew it should be very simpe :)

Comment: I put this comment as an answer, so other people find it easily :)

Answer (score 0):

Try save(list=filename,file=file_destination). Also, use better names for your variables. filename for an object which is not a file name is very odd.

Put this as answer, to ensure other people find it easily.